# ImageSource doesn't change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My XAML:

```
<Button Click="LikePost" BorderThickness="0" >
    <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding imagesource}" />
</Button>
```

Setting the imagesource for the first time works as expected but whenever I update the source string in my code the XAML does not update, and yes I have included INotifyPropertyChanghed:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _imagesource;
    public string imagesource
    {
        get { return _imagesource; }
        set
        {
            if (_imagesource == value) return;
            _imagesource = value;
            NotifyLikeImageChanged("like");
        }
    }
    private void NotifyLikeImageChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But you're sending the wrong property name, change this:

```
NotifyLikeImageChanged("like");
```

to this:

```
NotifyLikeImageChanged("imagesource");
```

Comment: @PhilippeMaes, don't call yourself stupid my friend, it's just something you happened to miss, it happens to all of us and often we're just too close to the project to see it.